# how to pass jquery variable value into css property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wan to pass js variable into css property value, I tried that but that looks weird,

so I can't understand how to do that.

```
$('.show-nav').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text() == 'Toggle Navigation' ? 'Close' : 'Toggle Navigation';
    $(this).text(text);
    $('nav').toggleClass('show');
    navHeight = $('nav').css('height');
});
<style type="text/css">
    .show {
        height: //need js value here, assuming navHeihgt;
    }
</style>
```

many thanks in advance.

**updated**

this is my css in media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 800px){

 #nav {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height linear 500ms;
    -webkit-transition:height ease-in-out 500ms;
 }

 .show {
    height:auto !important;
    transition:height linear 500ms;
    -webkit-transition:height ease-in-out 500ms;
 }
}
```

you can see that my `#nav` is no hidden with height:0; and when click event is triggered that `.show` class is assigned to that and it will show back when its height come back.

but it didn't animate by using `auto` value assigning, but when I choose any other specific value rather than auto it will animate. but its not animate using auto value thats why I was trying that.

Comment: Do you want to change the style of all elements with class `show`, or just the specific element? Because changing the value in a style declaration changes the style for all elements matching the selector.

Comment: no only for just specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define the style in your CSS, you can do this:

```
$('.show').height(navHeight);
```

To provide additional explanation - when the user clicks on the `show-nav` class the height of your `nav` element will be stored in the `navHeight` variable.  You can then apply this height to your `show` class with this jQuery.

Comment: this will assign like 
`element.style {
display: block;
}` in inline style I don't want it

Comment: I don't think that's the case.  There are no inline styles other than height being added in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hfhhuw96/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.show-nav').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text() == 'Toggle Navigation' ? 'Close' : 'Toggle Navigation';
    $(this).text(text);
    $('nav').toggleClass('show');
    navHeight = $('nav').css('height');
    $('.show').css('height', navHeight);
});
```

Comment: This will set `navHeight` to the height of the `nav` element, he wants the opposite.

Comment: Is my answer not identical to the one you submitted?

Comment: My bad, didn't see the last line.

Comment: @hsn0331 I'd be interested to hear your reasoning behind that statement. I can't even think of any other way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: do you have any other way to assign new property in existing class but without inline style?

Comment: @hsn0331 Nope, stylesheets are parsed immediately. Click events are fired when a user clicks that element. You cannot retroactively edit a stylesheet.

Comment: all I want that I want to animate my element as smooth using css and I tried jquery toggle and slideToggle functions too, but they are not very helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that. However, you can do something like

```
$('.show').css('height', navHeight);
```

Comment: it only just assign its value into inline, and I dont want inline style it will not show when you open the source of chrome like

`.show {
height:100px;
}`

Comment: I don't think there is any simple way of doing what you want. The css will appear if you use the Chrome Inspect Element tool (F12), so you will still be able to debug it.

Comment: And also, this is the way every website does it; Google, Microsoft, CNN, you name it. You will have to embrace this style, whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign javascript variable value to css properties.

Either you need to use,

```
   var navHeight = $('nav').css('height');
   $('.show').height(navHeight);
```

But it is displayed as inline css when you inspecting element in developer tools.

If you want same height needs to add for both nav and `.show-nav` selectors, try to include both this in common container and add height:auto for nav element.

Comment: but i dont want as inilne

Comment: If you try with both elements in the same container and height:auto property, inline css wont display. Did you try with that?